# How can i encode my email subject in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail

I get my mail from gmail.com with gmail gem.

```
gm = Gmail.connect addr, pass

in_m = gm.inbox.find(:before => 5.days.ago).last

puts in_m.text_part.body # shows "Привет ...."


puts in_m.subject  # shows "=?KOI8-R?B?z9Qg09XQxdLXwcraxdLB?=" 

puts in_m.subject.encoding    # shows #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

I tried

```
in_m.subject.encode("UTF-8")
in_m.subject.force_encoding("KOI8-R").encode("UTF-8")
in_m.subject.force_encoding("US-ASCII").encode("UTF-8")
```

this not help me

How i can encode the subject of my mail?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String like   `"=?KOI8-R?B?z9Qg09XQxdLXwcraxdLB?="` is the mime encoded word and this decoded `Base64, charset=KOI8-R`. Structure of mimeWord is `=?charset?decode type?decoded string ?=`. So if get part of string "z9Qg09XQxdLXwcraxdLB" and decoded this with Base64, then encode to UTF-8 all is OK. `Base64.decode64("z9Qg09XQxdLXwcraxdLB").encode("UTF-8")`. Question is closed